# How to get selected date in CalendarView in Xamarin

Tags: xamarin, calendarview

I'm having a problem on how to get the selected date from my Calendar View. I'm using Xamarin Studio which is c# and I can't use the solutions I've seen here because they're in java codes.

Does anyone know what to do?

Comment: are you using Xamarin.Android or Xamarin.Forms?

Comment: Please post what you have tried

Comment: I did exactly follow the code below. @InitLipton

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just set the `DateChange` Event in your view. Like following code:

```
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
{
    base.OnCreate(bundle);

    var calendar = FindViewById<CalendarView>(Resource.Id.mycalendarid);
    calendar.DateChange += CalendarOnDateChange;
}
```

And the event method:

```
private void CalendarOnDateChange(object sender, CalendarView.DateChangeEventArgs args)
{
    var newdatetime = new DateTime(args.Year, args.Month, args.DayOfMonth);
}
```

This method will be fired every time the date changed in your `CalendarView`.

Option 2: You just look at the [property from the calendarview](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CalendarView.html#getDate()):

```
calendar.Date
```

Android says following about this property (in Android it is a method):

> Gets the selected date in milliseconds since January 1, 1970 00:00:00

Comment: Thank you so much! This practically solved my problem :)

Comment: Ahm, do you know how to change the default color of the month and days title in calendar view? It's default color is white and it's really hard for me to see it in my app. It only turns to black when I clicked it.

Comment: Thanks @HunterWinchester. Please accept the answer, so this will maybe also help other users

Comment: Please search for this color-problem and if you don't find an answer, ask a new question on SO